# Showing a regression model is unidentifiable?

Tags: regression

I am following a tutorial in which we are looking at a risk regression model (the [Cox’s proportional hazards model](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Proportional_hazards_model). In particular, the hazard rate is modelled as
$$ \lambda(t) = \lambda_0(t) \exp(\mathbf{x}\beta)$$ where $\mathbf x$ is a vector of covariates and $\beta$ are the coefficients.

The tutorial goes on to say that $\mathbf x$ should not include a constant term corresponding to an intercept. If $\mathbf x$ includes a constant term corresponding to an intercept, the model becomes unidentifiable. They illustrate this:

Suppose the model does include an intercept term, i.e.
$$ \lambda(t) = \lambda_0(t) \exp(\beta_0 + \mathbf{x} \beta) = \lambda_0(t) \exp(\beta_0) \exp(\mathbf{x} \beta) $$
If $\tilde{\beta}_0 = \beta_0 + \delta$ and $\tilde{\lambda}_0(t) = \lambda_0(t) \exp(-\delta)$, then
$$ \lambda(t) = \tilde{\lambda}_0(t) \exp(\tilde{\beta}_0 + \mathbf{x} \beta) $$ as well,
making the model unidentifiable.

But I do not get how this makes it unidentifiable? I suppose I don't really understand what it means to be unidentifiable in the first place.

Comment: Your model *already* has an intercept term.  You can see it when you write $\log\lambda(t)=\log \lambda_0(t) + \mathbf x \beta:$ it corresponds to $\log\lambda_0(t).$